# Is this form of self grounding outlets really safe?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I am installing some of these outlets  ([link to lowes.com](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Eaton-Ivory-15-Amp-Duplex-Outlet-Commercial-10-Pack-Outlet/1001438124) or [link to amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KKNNPY)) which claim to have automatic grounding.

It looks to me like the grounding is provided solely by that little strip of copper wire at the "bottom" screw.

Is this a safe, sane thing people actually do? I am using metal boxes with romex, with the ground wire from the romex connected directly to the metal box.

It would be helpful to me if I can rely on this automatic grounding because I am installing 2-gang boxes, each with two outlets, and many of them have an outgoing line to feed another downstream box (e.g. if you manually ground the outlets, I have to connect the incoming ground + outgoing ground + metal box + 2 outlets, it gets to be troublesome to securely connect them all and fit everything in the box).

[image]

Comment: If this is a daft question, please feel free to vote to close. I felt the need to ask because the whole idea is kind of shocking to me.

Comment: The copper wire probably more of a gimmick.  If the metal box is properly grounded, the screws should work well enough.  Plastic boxes and ungrounded metal boxes still need extra.

Comment: Approved by UL, but always thought the Leviton style tab seemed more durable.

Comment: It's interesting that UK and USA practice on this are basically polar opposites. US practice seem to obsess about maintaining ground to the box even if some idiot removes the accesory and leaves the wires hanging, but be relatively slopping about grounding the actual accessory. UK practice is to ground the accessory and let the box be implicitly grounded by it.

Comment: Aside - your link is broken.  I get "You don't have permission to access http://www.lowes.com/pd/Eaton-Ivory-15-Amp-Duplex-Outlet-Commercial-10-Pack-Outlet/1001438124 on this server."  which may be an international restriction, or the link may be outdated.

Comment: @Criggie, Lowe’s website has … issues in general. The link seems to work fine for me, but for edification I linked to “ Eaton 15-Amp 125-volt Commercial Duplex Outlet, Ivory (10-Pack)”.

Comment: In Chicago we use metal boxes with *EMT*, with *no* ground wire. Same thing.

Comment: @Criggie does this amazon listing work for you?  It's higher resolution pictures let me see how the wire was placed around the screw; something I couldn't do with the Lowes side views.  https://www.amazon.com/EATON-BR15W-SP-L-125-Volt-Commercial-Receptacle/dp/B000KKNNPY?th=1

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight great spotting - Imma edit that into the question

Comment: Also, @negacao, the whole idea of grounding (and GFCI) is that it should _not_ be shocking to you! _ba-da-boom! I'll be here all week, don't forget to tip your waitress._

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea is that the copper wire provides constant contact of the screw to the metal body of the outlet.

If the outlet needed to be left a bit loose, so as to be flush with the wall and cover plate, the unit would be still be grounded to a metal box. Provided the box is grounded.

This is not novel.  Many of the better manufacturers of electrical products have this feature.

Provided all your metal boxes are grounded, I would be confident in using those outlets.

Comment: I did connect two of the outlets without explicitly grounding the outlets themselves - works perfectly, and I have a good ground from the outlets to the box. :)

Answer (score 6):

> Is this safe?

If the device is UL listed (and anything made by Eaton and sold in a physical, brick-and-mortar store that doesn't want to be sued out of existence will be) then yes, the UL certifies that the device is safe and meets the current (as of date of testing) NEC.

One of the advantages of spending the bit of extra money for the "commercial grade" devices is that you save time and space on install. I've done exactly the same thing for the addition to my house that I'm currently working on. It's well worth it, IMHO, for the simplicity and space savings to spend the extra buck or two for the higher grade device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're safe as houses.

The ground via the mounting screws just like switches do.

The issue with receptacles is that while you're wrestling a plug in or out, you could possibly push it in slightly and float it off the head of the bolts, causing poor ground contact. The double wiper on the screw shaft takes care of that.